# Visual Studio MSIX App Creation: Entry Point (.exe) not correct

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, visual-studio, msix

I have made a Windows Forms Project which hosts a WPF User Control (some kind of 3D Viewport), which are basically two "seperate" Projects.
Combining these two in one Main Project did work and i can access the Wpf with my Windows Forms App.
In the next step i wanted to create an "MSIX" App as Visual Studio 2019 suggests. So i inserted a "third" Project Template ( the MSIX project template ) and set up the References like in the official how to Guide. So that was mainly linking my "Main" Windows Forms Program as an Application in the MSIX Template and also setting it as an "Entry Point" for the App.

My WPF Program is referenced in my Main Program so i didnt have to link this in the MSIX Template again.
So far so good. The Debugging also doesnt bring any Errors.
But instead of opening the Main program (which is WinForms) as defined Entry Point, the Debugger opens just the WPF Application ( which is actually only accessible through a ButtonClick Event in the Windows Forms Programm) ....

In the .wapproj file:

```
<EntryPointProjectUniqueName>..\..\Visu 2.0 Core\Visu 2.0 Core\Visu 2.0 Core.csproj</EntryPointProjectUniqueName>
```

which is the Folderplace of my imported project (Main WindowsForms program part) which i do want to run..

I read about the property

```
<EntryPointexe/>
```

I now have two places where i could get my .exes from: the folder where i originally created the program
or the folder where i "built" the project anew together with the MSIX project specific stuff ( under a new project name)
So i dont really get if setting this could help out. It seems more to be an other reason why my App wont run/show the initial (windows)form.

My attempts to setting the  also somehow had an effect on the AppxManifest.xml file located in

```
..\source\repos\AppTest2\AppTest2\bin\AnyCPU\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

Has anybody an advice why my App Project (even though the entry point) doesnt want to know anything from my 1. Program Part ? ( it is just not run but the second program WPF though)

Answer (score 0):

@ Knally.Based on my test, I use Windows Forms Project as Entry Point in MSIX Template, it opens Windows Forms Project and WPF User Control is loaded when the button is clicked. You can check if the steps are consistent with yours. And if there is any problem, please let me know.

Here are my code in .wapproj file:

```
<EntryPointProjectUniqueName>..\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1.csproj</EntryPointProjectUniqueName>
```

The steps:

1. Create WPF App Project named WpfApp1 and build to WpfApp1.dll.
   【

1.Create a new WPF App Project

2.Add a User Control

3.Create control

4.Delete Window1 and App files in Solution Explorer

5.Project > WpfApp1 Properties > Application > Output Type = Class Library

6.Build solution... .dll file is in the bin/Release folder
】

2.Create Windows Forms App named WindowsFormsApp1 and add reference MyControl.dll.

【Right click References in WindowsFormsApp1->select **Add Reference…**->select **Browse** ->find and Add WpfApp1.dll->click OK】

The Form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using WpfApp1;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
            host.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            UserControl1 myControl = new UserControl1();
            host.Child = myControl;
            this.Controls.Add(host);
        }
    }
}
```

3.Create Windows Application Packaging Project named WapProjTemplate1.

【

1.Right click **Applications** -> click **Add Reference…**->Select **WindowsFormsApp1**->click OK

2.Double click **Package.appxmanifest**->Click **Packaging**->click **Choose Certificate…**->click
Create…->enter password->OK

3.modify your Configuration Manager as below:
[image]

[image]

4.Right click **WapProjTemplate1**->select **Publish**->select **Create App Packages…**->select Release for Architecture on **Select and configure packages** wizard as below:

[image]

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Example. I appreciate that.
I tried to change my WPF Project Output to .dll. 
But when i do i cant build the project anymore because it complains that it cant find any definitions for all the WPF Design Element Names like Labels, Sliders, Buttons.

Since my WPF Project is a bit of a "done" unit, i didnt want to do any big changes to it. 
Is there a simple explanation why my Element Names cant be found while debugging?